# How to return computed property that was created on Ajax request (hasMany relation)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create a computed property in my model, but because of the Ajax request that gets called when using `get`, I can't return the value (I want to calculate the percentage of the tasks that are done and assigned to this project)

**Model**

```
Docket.Project = DS.Model.extend({
  name:        DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  number:      DS.attr('string'),
  archived:    DS.attr('boolean'),
  customer:    DS.belongsTo('customer'),
  tasks:       DS.hasMany('task',{ async: true }),

  // custom attributes
  progress: function() {

    var done = 0,
        progress = 0;

    this.get('tasks').then(function(tasks) {
      tasks.forEach(function(task) {
        if (task.get('status') == 5) done++
      });

      progress = (done / tasks.get('length')) * 100;

    });

    console.log(progress);

    return progress;

  }.property('tasks')
});
```

**Template**

```
<span class="progress"><span class="bar"></span>{{progress}}%</span>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to add `@each` to your observer. Try this:

```
progress: function() {
    var done = 0,
        progress = 0;

    this.get('tasks').forEach(function(task) {
        if (task.get('status') == 5) done++;
    });

    progress = (done / tasks.get('length')) * 100;

    console.log(progress);
    return progress;
  }.property('tasks.@each.status')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still returns 0 :(

Comment: What other methods are available besides for forEach? Let's say I want to pull out task number 1 - how would I do that?

Comment: this.get('tasks')[0] should do the job. I think this.get('tasks').firstObject() may work, too.